# Please add a tag for elliptic curves

Tags: support, status-declined, tags

[Here](https://superuser.com/questions/556188/how-to-generate-a-self-signed-elliptic-curves-certificate). My carma doesn't allow to do this.

Comment: We don't have karma, we have reputation. And you haven't really said why we need to add a tag for elliptic curves.

Comment: >We don't have karma, we have reputation.> - What's the difference? :)

Comment: semantics - you earn reputation for good answer. You earn karma for good actions. In addition, you've posted a question for another site here - security.SE has its own meta site

Comment: Fixed =========

Comment: Journeyman Geek, if you already found time to edit my post, can you do it? :)

Comment: I'm not sure this warrants a tag, honestly.

Comment: ^ that. The question is closed, and I don't see elliptic curve cryptography being a common question here. Its fine as it is.

Answer (score 3):

Doesn't warrant one right now. The current lot of tags suffice.

If it becomes more of a thing on the site to ask about them, it'll happen that way.